# Where can i find goblins?

Tags: torchlight-2

In which map/dungeon can i find goblins? I have unique weapon with augment that wants me to kill 20 goblins for it to upgrade, and i can't find them anywhere. I am currently at the beginning of act II.

Comment: What act are you on? What level are you?

Comment: @Dycker If you have fully read my question you would have noticed i already said I'm at the beginning of act 2. And I'm lv26 atm.

Comment: Ah, Goblinskewer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emberscratch Mines - are your best bet at meeting goblins
Its main enemy type in there

ACT I
- Frosted Hils - 
Dugeon

If you travel back there from ACT II all enemies will respawn

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i forgot i fought them there. Got my augmentation now, sadly got useless one lol.